# r(tau) within of H´s level curves

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, functions

Im currently working on a math project and have one question regarding level curves. I´ve been given a function

$$H(\theta,\omega)=\frac{1}{2}\omega^2-C\theta-\cos{\theta}$$

And I´ve shown that if $r(\tau)$ is a solution to $H$, then $H$ is a constant.
$$r(\tau)=(\theta(\tau),\omega(\tau))$$

Now the question is to argument that $r(\tau)$ is whitin $H$´s level curves. Is that because my knowledge of $H(r(\tau))$ being constant?
Thank you for the help!

Comment: Yes, if $r(\tau)$ makes $H$ constant, then it must lie on one of $H$'s level curves. The level curves of $H$ is exactly $H=C$ where $C$ is an arbitrary constant.

Comment: By the way, here is a tutorial for MathJax, which you can use to type equations: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference. It would be very beneficial to you to be on this site if you learn it.